# FormCollection parameter is empty while using @Ajax.BeginForm and @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, formcollection, ajaxhelper

I've went through whole bunch of SO questions regarding my problem and I wasn't able to find a solution, so I've decided to post this question. The problem is that `FormColection fc` is empty when I do that Ajax POST request by clicking the search button from `_Sidebar.cshtml`. What am I missing here?

Code part:
`_MyLayout.cshtml:`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Results", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "d_content", LoadingElementId = "spinner", OnBegin = "ToggleContent", OnComplete = "ToggleContent" },null))
{
    <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div id="a_sidebar">
            @{ Html.RenderAction("_Sidebar"); }
        </div>
        <aside class="right-side">
            <section class="content">
                <img id="spinner" src="~/Content/img/lightbox-ico-loading.gif" style="display: none;">
                <div id="d_content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </section>
        </aside>
    </div>
}
```

`_Sidebar.cshtml:`

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>F1</label> 
                        @Html.ListBox("ddF1", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["ddF1"])
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>F2</label>
                        @Html.ListBox("ddF2", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["ddF2"])
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        @Html.ListBox("ddStatusFilter", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["ddStatusFilter"])
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("tbName")
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

<li class="treeview">

            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Clear Filters</button>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Search", "Results", "Search", new { }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "d_content", LoadingElementId = "spinner", OnBegin = "ToggleContent", OnComplete = "ToggleContent" }, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @style = "color: white;" })
            </div>
        </li>
```

`SearchController.cs:`

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public PartialViewResult Results(FormCollection fc)
{
    //TODO: Implement filtering through FormCollection in passed parameter
    //      but that freakin' fc var is empty
    var model = db.vw_MainTable.ToList();
    return PartialView("_SearchResultGrid", model);
}
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried making the search link a Submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code, It looks like you don't need a form tag covering your entire html. You can place it in the `_Sidebar.cshtml` like this.

Also replace the action link with a submit button (check below code).

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Results", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "d_content", LoadingElementId = "spinner", OnBegin = "ToggleContent", OnComplete = "ToggleContent" },null))
{
             <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>F1</label> 
                        @Html.ListBox("ddF1", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["ddF1"])
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>F2</label>
                        @Html.ListBox("ddF2", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["ddF2"])
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        @Html.ListBox("ddStatusFilter", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["ddStatusFilter"])
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("tbName")
                    </div>
                </li>
           </ul>    
           <li class="treeview">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Clear Filters</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn"> Search</button>
            </div>
           </li
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple reasons for this. In my case, it was happening because my form fields only had the ID property and not the Name property.

After adding the Name property to the input fields, the Controller could see them just fine.